# How should I load deeplearn js?

Tags: javascript, deeplearn.js

At https://deeplearnjs.org/index.html#demos , it said the API will be available as 'dl', here's a print screen of the site:

---

[image]

---

but when I tried putting

```
<head><script src="https://unpkg.com/deeplearn"></script></head>
<body><script>var math = new dl.NDArrayMathGPU();
```

it prompted  Uncaught ReferenceError: dl is not defined

How should I load it then?

Comment: Anything in the console or network tabs that give any clues, like did the Api actually load?

Comment: It becomes available after a few seconds, I think `dl` is set asynchronously somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation might have a mistake.

It seems that the library is globally available as `deeplearn` instead of `dl`

Answer (score 0):

either change dl to deeplearn or include this line

dl = deeplearn

For lots of examples try

https://hpssjellis.github.io/deeplearnjs-javascript-examples/